# Cloud IDE for Google App Engine using GO

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, cloud9-ide

I've been struggling to find an online IDE which supports Go and Google App Engine.  Codeenvy supports it using python, while Cloud9 runs python 2.6 (which isn't compatible with GAE), and the update doesn't work.

Is there any IDE that will allow me to develop and deploy Go to GAE?

Answer (score 1):

Python 2.7.3 should be installable from command line in Cloud9 via `c9pm install python27` (see also [the github repo](https://github.com/c9/c9pm/tree/master/packages/python27-2.7.3).

Answer (score 0):

[Koding](https://koding.com/?c=ideh) comes with Go, Python2 & 3, and best of all gives you a normal Ubuntu VM with full root access! It will work great with Go and GAE :)